# Using Tabs and Fragments to display my Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-pageradapter

i have  an existing App  and i want  to add tabs to navigate between layouts
i did  found several tutorials and  topic on the same subject but am beginner on Android  and i found some dificults to do this so i hape if  someone can help me do it
btw i did use the TabbedActivity in Android studio it did   add  tabs  but i don't  know how  to implements layouts to  those tabs  and still have  the Tab bar   cause i did this

```
if(tab.getPosition()==0){
         Intent intent = new Intent("com.blooddonor.blooddonor.profil");
         startActivity(intent);

      }
```

and  i don't  won't  things  to be liek those  it  opens another tabs not displayed on the  principale layout that have the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use fragments and not activities to use tab navigation.  What you are doing is launching a new activity which will not have the tab navigation enabled.  I'd suggest creating a tabbed activity and looking at how it's constructed.  Here's a very basic tabbed navigation from the stock sample.

```
public class TabbedActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });


// set up your tabs here instead using this for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
// Here is where you would implement which fragment to set
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeholder, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you !  but how can i create fragments and how  do i use them into to this tabbed Activity

Comment: You can create fragments the same way you create activities.  I'm assuming you are using android studio, it's just File > New > Fragment and then select the type of fragment you want.  To add it to the page, you either need to use the ViewPager I referenced above, or provide a fragment container like this:

  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: Then you'll need to use fragment manager:
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
and then change the fragment like so:
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, PlaceHolderFragment.newInstance(), "fragment tag")
                        .commit();